# print (dummy) is not printing anything. is it empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`pathway.txt` contains lines like this (below)

```
a,
b,0
c,8
d,
```

`dummy` should print `[a,d]`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
def pathway(file):
    dict={}
    dummy=[]
    file_object=open(file, "r+")
    for line in file_object:
        a, b = line.split(',')
        if b == '':
            dummy.append(a)
    print (dummy)

pathway("pathway.txt")
```

Comment: So what *does* it print? You should, at the very least, get `[]` printed.

Comment: `b` will *never* be equal to `''`; it'll be equal to `'\n'` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the line separator. All but perhaps the last `line` string will end in a `\n` newline character. This makes `b` equal to `'\n'`, not the empty string.

You should strip whitespace from `b` first:

```
for line in file_object:
    a, b = line.split(',')
    if not b.strip():
        dummy.append(a)
```

The [`str.strip()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) returns a new string with all whitespace (newlines included) from the start and end removed. You could also apply it to the `line` first, before splitting:

```
a, b = line.strip().split(',')
```

but then you would leave whitespace after the comma in place, as well as remove whitespace at the start of the value assigned to `a`.

You should really use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read comma-separated data:

```
def pathway(file):
    dummy = []

    with open(file) as file_object:
        reader = csv.reader(file_object)
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) == 1:
                dummy.append(row[0])

    print(dummy)
```

Comment: or `b.rstrip()`